Can I ask whether films have been produced about a certain period in history?
I want to figure out if any films have been produced regarding the Mongol conquest of the Abbasid caliphate, and specifically the sacking of Baghdad by Hulegu Khan in 1258.
I read the guideline for on- and off-topic questions as part of the tour, but it was not entirely clear to me whether this would be on or off-topic (i.e. what does "locating" a film mean, exactly? Is it about a known film that you want to get a hold of, or figuring out whether one exists) ; so - I'm asking here whether that's a kind of question I could post on the main site.

This wouldn't be an ID-This question (because you aren't asking us to find a specific film), but you are asking for recommendations, which is forbidden.
Per the FAQ

Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
...
Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

The close reason is as follows;

Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic.


What about @galacticninja's answer then?

@einpoklum - The problem is that you're not interested in whether there has or hadn't been. You're after a list of them.

Based on similar questions I've found, your inquiry appears to be on-topic. Here are a few examples that share similarities with what you're asking:

Has there ever been a drama film with an unreliable death scene confession?
Has there been a movie produced without a title sequence?
Are there any movies whose name changed after released in theaters?
Have there ever been movies with the same name, released in the same year?

While I can't predict how the community will vote, it's worth noting that your question might resemble a recommendation request (as Valorum pointed out), which could potentially lead to downvotes.
To increase your chances of a positive reception, I'd suggest a slight modification to your approach. Instead of asking for examples of films about the Mongol conquest of the Abbasid caliphate, consider using the first-appearance tag and framing your question as:
"What was the first film to depict the Mongol sacking of Baghdad in 1258?"
Questions using the first-appearance format are generally well-received and considered on-topic in our community. This approach allows you to explore the topic while staying within our guidelines.

Ugh. I hate concealed list/recommendation questions .
